# Is there a way to nest enums in c++ without namespace?

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, compiler-construction, code-generation

I'm implementing a byte code generator for a given AST. While creating the expression class I noticed the distincition between unary and binary operators. For simplicity unum was the go-to solution, so I nested the enuns this way:

```
enum EXP_TYPE
{
    enum BINARY
    {
        PLUS,
        MINUS,
        MULTIPLY,
        DIV,
        ...
    };
    enum UNARY
    {
        PLUS,
        MINUS,
        POINTER,
        INC,
        ...
    };
};
```

Of course this code throws warnings informing this is not allowed. So I searched a bit on stackoverflow and other sources, and found the solution of using `namespace` instead of `enum` for **EXP_TYPE** declaration. But the problem now is the use inside the expression class:

```
class expression
{
    expression *right_exp;
    expression *left_exp;
    EXP_TYPE type;
    ...
};
```

The use of **EXP_TYPE** is not allowed anymore due to it being a `namespace` instead of a `enum` type. What I intented to make was a generic `enum` declaration that could be used as a atribute inside a class, in here generic means that it could be **BINARY** or **UNARY**, that is, the atribute `EXP_TYPE type` could have assignments and comparisons like:

```
 expression exp1;
 exp1.type = EXP_TYPE::BINARY::PLUS;
 exp1.type = EXP_TYPE::UNARY::PLUS;
```

Is there a way to make these simple generic types without using `namespace` in the way presented, or without the need of creating a class hierarchy for unary and binary operators ?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: That's not how enumerations work. An enumeration is a way to introduce symbolic integer constants, sequentially numbered. So for e.g. `enum EXP_TYPE { BINARY_PLUS, UNARY_PLUS}` then `BINARY_PLUS` is equal to `0` and `UNARY_PLUS` is equal to `1`. With your nested enums, what value would `PLUS` have? How would `BINARY::PLUS` differ from `UNARY::PLUS`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can imagine `BINARY::DIV == UNARY_PLUS-1` (ish), if we had a hypothetical subscoping of enums. But we don't. And, to be fair, we don't need them either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took this as puzzle to find out how close I could come to what the OP requested.

This is what I got (though I must admit it looks a bit scaring):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

struct ExpType {
  struct Unary {
    enum {
      Plus, Minus, Pointer, Inc,
      N
    };
  };
  struct Binary {
    enum {
      Plus = Unary::N, Minus, Multiply, Div,
      N
    };
  };
  enum {
    N = Binary::N
  };

  int value;

  ExpType(int value = 0): value((assert(value >= 0 && value < N), value)) { }
  ~ExpType() = default;
  ExpType(const ExpType&) = default;
  ExpType& operator=(const ExpType&) = default;

  operator int () { return value; }
};

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < ExpType::N; ++i) {
    ExpType expType = i;
    switch (expType) {
#define CASE(TYPE) case TYPE: std::cout << #TYPE "\n"; break
      CASE(ExpType::Unary::Plus);
      CASE(ExpType::Unary::Minus);
      CASE(ExpType::Unary::Pointer);
      CASE(ExpType::Unary::Inc);
      CASE(ExpType::Binary::Plus);
      CASE(ExpType::Binary::Minus);
      CASE(ExpType::Binary::Multiply);
      CASE(ExpType::Binary::Div);
#undef CASE
      default: std::cout << "Unknown expression type!\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
ExpType::Unary::Plus
ExpType::Unary::Minus
ExpType::Unary::Pointer
ExpType::Unary::Inc
ExpType::Binary::Plus
ExpType::Binary::Minus
ExpType::Binary::Multiply
ExpType::Binary::Div
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6e38023e0fc209e)

However, I must admit I personally would surely prefer what was recommended in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58935349/7478597).

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot create scopes inside of enums.

Instead, categorise your enumerations with longer names (e.g. `EXP_TYPE::BINARY_PLUS`).